# How to find valid date on tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to find weather the column contains valid date or not like

`'00-jan-00'` is ***not valid*** and 
`'01-jan-1900'` ***is valid***

Comment: Make the column a date or datetime type then it can't be anything else but valid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select * from Table where IsDate(Column)=1
```

Comment: Caveat: it won't help you find out if someone's specified a US date if you're validating UK dates.